# Why is this C++ array template class initialized with garbage values?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

Using Visual Studio 2019, I'm attempting to create a template array class where `T`is the type of the array and `S` its size:

```
// Array.hpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename T, int S> class Array {

    T m_array[S];
    
public:

    Array() : Array(0) {}

    Array(const T& val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) { m_array[i] = val; }
    }

    template<typename E> Array(const E& val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) { m_array[i] = static_cast<T>(val); }
    }

    int size() const { return S; }
    T operator[](int position) const { return m_array[position]; }
    T& operator[](int position) { return m_array[position]; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array& a) {
        os << '[';
        if (a.size() > 0) { os << a[0]; }
        for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
            os << ', ' << a[i];
        }
        return os << ']';
    }
};
```

However, when I create an object of `Array` and print it, I find weird values mixed into the output:

```
// main.cpp
#include "Array.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Array<int, 10> a1(3);
    Array<double, 10> a2(3.14);
    Array<int, 10> a3(5.9);

    cout << a1 << endl;
    cout << a2 << endl;
    cout << a3 << endl;
}
```

Gives me this output:

[image]

Comment: Please, don't post text as image.

Comment: `', '` -> `", "`

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
', '
```

Is a multi-character literal.  That's not at all what you want.  Replace it with:

```
", "
```

And if you can, turn on the warning in your compiler for multi-character literals.  In GCC that is `-Wmultichar`.